# How to store selected items from android multiplechoice list, max number of selected items allowed should be 5?

Tags: android, list, listview, checkbox, multiple-choice

```
final String[] listContent = {"1", "2", "3", "4" ,"5","6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ,"11" };
ListView list;

//adapter
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent));
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


//on item click method
StringBuilder vota = new StringBuilder();
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for (int i = 1; i < listContent.length; i++) {

        Log.i("Test", listContent[i] + ": " + checked.get(i));

        if(checked.get(i) == true)          
           { 
                           count++;
            if(count<=5)
             {
            vota.append(" "+listContent[i]);
            Log.i("vert",vota.toString());
             }
            else
            {
                     //it displays an alert dialogbox   
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("You can't select more than 5 items!")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
             });
        checked.delete(i);
        AlertDialog ert = builder.create();
        ert.show();

           }

             }
    }

}
```

Comment: you have already implemented the code for limiting the number of selections to 5, is there any problem in it? some supporting text with your code would have been helpful.

Comment: the problem is that the dialogbox is displayed after selecting 3 items ...and when u click close, it is displayed again 2 times. after closing the dialog box everytime u select an item the dialogbox appears again.

Comment: i think there are some problems at the logic of loop ...it isnt working well